# If $a_{n_k}$ denotes a subsequence of $a_n$. Why is $n_k \geq k$ for all $k$.?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit. Now going in the backwards direction, I know it is true because the sequence is a subsequence of itself. But what about proving if a sequence converges then every subsequence converges to the same limit.

I do not understand the notation $a_{n_k}$, $a_n$, $n_k$ and $k$
I know that subsequence need to be in order just like in the original sequence. Can someone please clarify the notation and explain why  $n_k \geq k$ for all $k$.?

Comment: Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: the indexes of the subsequence are strictly increasing, thus $n_{k+1}-n_{k}\ge 1$ summing this telescoping sum gives $n_k\ge k$.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that the indices of the original sequence start at $0$; the proof is almost identical if they start at $1$ (or indeed at any other integer). Clearly $n_0$, the index of the first term of the subsequence, must be at least $0$: $n_0\ge 0$. Now suppose that $n_k\ge k$ for some $k$. We must have $n_{k+1}>n_k$, and $n_{k+1}$ and $n_k$ are both integers, so $n_{k+1}\ge n_k+1$. Finally, $n_k\ge k$, so $n_{k+1}\ge n_k+1\ge k+1$. By induction we conclude that $n_k\ge k$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$. (For me $\Bbb N$ includes $0$.)

Comment: Hi professor Scott, thanks for answering. so $n$ is the index of the sequence, $n_k$ is the index of the subsequence then what is $k$?

Comment: @Negrawh: The subsequence is $\langle a_{n_0},a_{n_1},a_{n_2},\ldots\rangle$, so $k$ is the index of the term in the subsequence, and $n_k$ is the index of that same term in the original sequence. And $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle n_0,n_1,n_2,\ldots\rangle$ is the sequence consisting of the indices of the terms in the original sequence that we are keeping in the subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

The $n_k$ ($k=1,2,3,\ldots$) are a subsequence of $\Bbb N$, i.e., $n_1\ge 1$ and for all $k$, $n_{k+1}>n_k$. Then $n_k\ge k$ follows by induction.